How do I translate "he/she/it has been [doing something]" into German, referring to something that is still going on?
I am working on a translation of a video game into German and I am confused about how to refer to something which has been going on in the past and continues to in the present. I have this line:

All the troll's valuables are in that little bag it's been guarding...

The troll is still guarding the bag and has presumably been doing so continuously. It does not seem quite right to just say "...in der kleinen Tasche, die er bewacht," although that is what Google Translate recommends. I do not want to use the past tense either, because I do not want to imply that he has stopped guarding the bag. The closest I can think of is "...in that little bag it's still guarding," i.e.:

Alle Wertsachen des Trolls liegen in dieser kleinen Tasche, die er noch bewacht

but is there any way to convey the meaning more precisely?

I somehow suspect, that bewachen might not be the optimum choice  of the verb, since it suggests, that this is the main task. If the bag is little, the troll may either carry it around or just keep an eye on it, which would translate to im Auge behalten.


Alle Wertsachen des Trolls stecken in dieser kleinen Tasche, die er (da) bewacht.

Things don't liegen in bags, but stecken or sein.
Use Präsens, that's sufficient to indicate that the action is ongoing. If you want to make it more clear that this thing is happening right now, add a da. That adds focus to the bewachen action which marks it as immediate rather than timeless.
Noch marks the end of the action it as imminent. This would make me question why. Is he going to abandon it?

German has a much simpler tense system than English.
"die er bewacht" is fine. Native speakers of German understand from context that the guarding probably started at some point in the past, this doesn't need to be explicitly said.
"die er noch bewacht" (= "which it is still guarding") makes me think "why is it going to stop guarding them?"
If you absolutely need to express the idea that it's been guarding them for a while, you can say exactly that: "die er die ganze Zeit (schon) bewacht" (= "which it has been guarding the entire time (already)"; but this seems like a lot of unnecessary words.

Fun fact: Speakers from the Ruhr area have a progressive tense: die er noch am Bewachen ist. It does not exist in standard German, tho.

I think the upshot in general is that German speakers are used to filling in this kind of tense information from context than English speakers. So unless the meaning from context would be unclear you can just leave it out. The German present tense includes all meanings, so (mentally at least) translate "bewacht" as "watches/is watching/has been watching" not as "watches".

note that the position of the "(schon)" in the last example very slightly changes the meaning: as written "die er die ganze Zeit (schon) bewacht" expresses "this has been going on for a while", whereas "die er (schon) die ganze Zeit bewacht" (my instinctive first thought) would put a meaning of "I'm negating a claim that the situation has changed to him guarding it. This has always (in the relevant timespan) been the case and is not a new development".

Can we say "..., die er bewachen ist."? Would that be proper German, and convey the fact that he has been doing it continuously?

@SylvainGadenne only in very colloquial language and then it means something like "which it is busy guarding", not the intended meaning either

@SylvainGadenne: "die er am Bewachen ist", but it sounds so colloquial that it would come across as the product of an inept writer. "dir er bewachen ist" is, colloquially, also possible, but it has yet another meaning as it is like an ellipsis of "die er bewachen gegangen ist", i.e. implying it has walked away to guard the bag (which would somehow be elsewhere in this case) and is thus absent.

@O.R.Mapper yes. The "am [infinitive] sein" construction is actually very common in some dialects, but it's not proper Standard German.

Thanks all for your answers to my question!

I would use this phrase to express your intention:

Der Troll hat alle seine Wertsachen in dieser kleinen Tasche die er ständig bewacht.


"Wertsachen" is a very formal expression. You would use it for anything that has some value e.g. your cellular phone, your keys, your wallet etc. I assume this is a kind of adventure game that is to be translated into German. The more adequate expression here would be "seine Schätze" or "seine wertvollen Dinge".
I agree to the proposed translations given so far:
All the troll's valuables are in that little bag it's been guarding...
Alle seine Schätze verwahrt der Troll in der kleinen Tasche, die er bewacht....
In other words, present tense is the right choice.

In German, use the simple present.
Note:  Even in English, I think your construction is poorly worded (although probably grammatically correct).  Better to say "it is guarding" if emphasizing a specific troll/bag/situation.  It is understood that a continuing action started some time in the past.  But we are a lot more interested in the present situation and grabbing the gold, than the past behavior of the troll.)
Or even just "guards" if emphasizing a more general characteristic of troll behavior and bag defense, for player consideration.
I would probably only use the compound past as you did to answer a question like, "What's the troll been doing the last few minutes?" But that puts the focus on the troll, not the bag, which doesn't gibe with the beginning of the sentence.
